# Add Digital Signature field using Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, itext, export-to-pdf

I have a web form which displays the details to be filled in by the users.
The form data is saved in a table. Created a Jasper Reports which fetches the data from the database table and generates the report in PDF format. Have a couple of questions.

> Is there any way to add a digital signature field using Jasper reports.
>
> And then digitally sign in the created signature field

Found this [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527430/digital-signature), which says it's not possible using jasper reports.

Comment: Yes, you can not do this using jasper reports. You can use REST API of jasper to download the report and then use iText PDF to add a digital signature.

Comment: It is not implemented. But since iText is already part of jasper reports you can add the functionality by yourself. (or follow Fahad Anjum's advice)